# R - igraph hides edges with inverted source and sink vertex

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I need to draw a graph where all the edges are easily spotted (there are labels on), but the "igraph" package completely overlap the edges that has connect two vertices, but don't share the source and the sink.

Here's an example. I found the layout.circle useful since I need to fix the vertices of my graph.

```
library("igraph")
Edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                    to   = c(2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1))
g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(Edges))
plot(g, layout = layout.circle(g, params = list(root = 1)), 
     edge.label = letters[1:6])
```

As you can see, the edges #1 and #2 are completely overlapped.
I tried to use the `edge.curved` option, but the result is identically disappointing:

```
plot(g, layout = layout.circle(g, params = list(root = 1)), edge.label = letters[1:6],
 edge.curved = TRUE)
```

Now there are two couples of edges overlapped, and they're unrecognizable.
Do you know any way to help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: By "inverted source and sink vertex" you mean edges in opposite directions between the same pair of vertices? Because in your graph, this is not what you have. You have exactly the same edges twice, at least between (2,3) and (1,3). That's why the labels end up on top of each other.

Comment: The first example shows what I need to fix, where the edges 1-> 2 and 2->1 are overlapped. The other example is there to show that the solution with edge.curved doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with the `edge.curved` argument which uses the `autocurve.edges` function to compute edge curvature.  Apparently this doesn't properly recognize your situation.  You have the option of supplying your own set of curvatures so you might try something like the following:

```
E(g)$label <- letters[1:6]
edges_undir <- t(apply(get.edgelist(g), 1, range))
curves <- unlist(lapply( split(E(g)$label, list(edges_undir[,1], edges_undir[,2])),
                     function(x) { seq(0,.5, length.out=length(x))}))

plot(g, layout = layout.circle(g, params = list(root = 1)), edge.label=E(g)$label, 
     edge.curved = curves)
```

which gives the plot

[image]